# CLR Runtime error framework 3.5 - System.Security.HostProtectionException

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sqlclr

I´ve created a CLR Runtime dll following the steps of this post - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b732a134-33ba-4880-838d-33fb93887d12/decript-data-on-field-level-that-was-encrypted-on-an-oracle-system?forum=transactsql
It was created for SQL Server 2012 and it works perfectly.
The problem is that the client database is SQL Server 2008 and a new project had to be created for due to the framework 3.5.
So a new dll was created and when I call it on SQL Server 2008 I´m having the following error message.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "DecryptDataDecimal": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: MayLeakOnAbort

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
at UserDefinedFunctions.Decrypt_AES(Byte[] cypherText, Byte[] Key, Byte[] IV)
at UserDefinedFunctions.DecryptDataDecimal(String EncryptedData)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You recompiled with a target framework of 3.5? What references did you add, or what classes are you using? Was there more to the stack dump in that error message?

Comment: The problem is that I´m using System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged and according to this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645949%28v=sql.105%29.aspx the permissions of the assembly need to be changed to UNSAFE. I was able to create a new assembly with 'sa' priviledges but I´m not able to execute it with another user. Only 'sa' can execute it... Is it possible to give permissions to this user to execute this assembly?

Comment: adding the loginname to server roles - sysadmin solved the issue